# ¿Como mantener seleccionado un dato combobox anidado al recargar la pagina?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, combobox

Hola a todos bien quisiera saber si es posible mantener seleccionado un dato de un combobox anidado y que al mismo tiempo este dato que se selecciono mande a traer a los demas datos automaticamente, cabe alaclarar que ya tengo el combobox anidado solo quiero que los demas datos salgan automaticamente. sin necesidad que yo este seleccionando el dato aqui el codigo y las imagenes, El que quiero qu salga automaticamente es el que dice Municipio y de ahi los demas  [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora muestro el codigo de mi php de municipio, de el js y de donde tengo alojada la variable en el formulario

Primero de municipio

```
    <?php
require_once 'conexions.php';

function getMunicipio(){
  $mysqli = getConn();
  $query = "SELECT * FROM Municipio";
  $result = $mysqli->query($query);
  $listas = '<option value="0">Elige una opción</option>';
  while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
    $listas .= "<option value='$row[id]'>$row[nombre]</option>";
  }
  return $listas;
}

echo getMunicipio();
?>
```

luego de el js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'cargar_municipio.php'
  })
  .done(function(listas_rep){
    $('#lista_municipio').html(listas_rep)
  })
  .fail(function(){
    alert('Hubo un errror al cargar los municipos')
  })

  $('#lista_municipio').on('change', function(){
    var id = $('#lista_municipio  ').val()
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'cargar_categoria.php',
      data: {'id': id}
    })
    .done(function(listas_rep){
      $('#lista_categoria').html(listas_rep)
    })
    .fail(function(){
      alert('Hubo un errror al cargar las categorias')
    })

    var id_lista = $('#lista_categoria').val()
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'cargar_subcategoria.php',
      data: {'id': id}
    })
    .done(function(listas_rep){
      $('#lista_subcategoria').html(listas_rep)
    })
    .fail(function(){
      alert('Hubo un errror al cargar los segundo')
    })
```

Y ahora el apartado del formulario donde tengo la variable por si quieren saber cual es

```
  <div class="row">

                      <label id="f1" for="Fuente">Municipio:</label>
                      <select  id="lista_municipio" name="Ubicacion" class="form-control">
                      </select>



                    <label id="f1" for="Fuente">Categoria:</label>
                    <select id="lista_categoria" name="Categoria" class="form-control">
                    </select>



                      <label id="f1" for="Fuente">Subcategoria:</label>
                      <select id="lista_subcategoria" name="Subcategoria" class="form-control">
                      </select>

</div>
```

Comment: **[Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour)**. para esta y futuras preguntas lee 
**[cómo crear una buena pregunta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)**. Creo que te falta mas código; al organizar el código javascript parece que faltan paréntesis y cierres. **Debes [edit] tu pregunta** con los errores que tengas. Puedes consultar aquí [qué funciones tiene Stack Overflow en Español para que puedas organizar el código o lo que coloques en tus preguntas y/o respuestas](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/a/1453/78).

Answer (score 1):

A tus `select` agrégales una clase la que tu quieras puede ser `.selectChange` y agrega esto al final de tu JS:

```
$(".selectChange").each(function(){
 $(this).change();
});
```

Lo que hace esta función es buscar todos los elementos con esta clase y ejecutar un `change()`, como si tu los cambiaras manualmente.

HTML:

```
<div class="row">

    <label id="f1" for="Fuente">Municipio:</label>
    <select  id="lista_municipio" name="Ubicacion" class="form-control selectChange">
    </select>



    <label id="f1" for="Fuente">Categoria:</label>
    <select id="lista_categoria" name="Categoria" class="form-control selectChange">
    </select>



    <label id="f1" for="Fuente">Subcategoria:</label>
    <select id="lista_subcategoria" name="Subcategoria" class="form-control selectChange">
    </select>

</div>
```

Espero te sirva.

Comment: Hola, perdon por contestar hasta ahora, pero mira (me voy a basar en la imagen) lo que quiero es que  (Municipio) se seleccione automaticamente que seleccione puebla en automatico, y en base a eso se seleccionen los demas campos   en automatico el anidado ya lo tengo. puse tu codigo js y puse las classes como dices pero no hace el que se seleccionen automatico. ya logre poner en (Munocipio) Puebla en automatico pero no me arroja los demas campos de Categoria y subcategoria en automatico, se quedan en blanco. no se si me explique pero eso es lo qe quiero , gracias por tu respuesta

Comment: siempre va a ser puebla o lo traes los valores de los select de la base de datos?